# How do i choose architecture for my scraping web app?

Tags: php, python, mysql, json, ajax

I have written a bunch of simple Python scripts that parse and scrape information on the web and store it in JSON files, so that I can access that data and work with it. Now I want to build a web application on top of my project. Basic use case would be:

1. User inputs his search request in html form.
2. User gets response without reloading the page.

Seems fairly simple, however a couple of questions arises when it comes to choosing a technology, or technology stack:

**1. SQL vs JSON.**

I store my data in a JSON files now which seems to work quite nice: I have an array with 700-800 objects of about 5-6 key-value pairs of unicode strings and urls:

```
{"title": "some title", "img": "some-img-cdn.com/serve/img11484846435.png", "article": "item_article", "url": "some_url.com/group/item_article.html"}
```

My old laptop search that data blazingly fast, but what about the web? What will happen, when multiple users will try to access the same file at the same time? What about Python's GIL and the way linux serves files? The question is, how much slower is reading and searching in JSON file as opposed to SQL database?

**2. Python in PHP way.**

I use Python as a general-purpose language, I write backend in PHP. This time not only do I want to write parsing/crawling part of this app in Python, but I want to create and serve web pages using Python. I get used to write PHP in a simple way, something like the following:

```
$search = $_POST['search_request'];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE title='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($search) . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo $page;
mysqli_close($conn);
```

However, it finds out that Python gets quite complex when it comes to developing a web app. You have to use a full-fledged web framework such as Django which seems as quite an overkill to me, especially in my case when I do not need to worry about storing user's data, no sign up or sign in is required, no email checking. So, second question is, can I form and serve valid html documents with Python using inline tags as with Apache + PHP stack? 
like the following:

```
echo "<h1>$item->title</h1>"
echo "<p>$item->description</p>"
```

If not, can it be done significantly easier than in Django using all that MVC (also they call it MTV and I haven't figured out why yet) stuff?

**3. AJAX**

Third part comes right about serving that content in search result container without reloading page. How do i access local JSON file with jQuery or should I query my server with a XHR?

Comment: This question is going to be pegged as too opinionated and not a good stack overflow (or any stack exchange) question. I'd ask this on hackernews or some subreddit.

Comment: How come it's opinionated? What I'm asking is basically:

1. Which is faster JSON or SQL (no way it's opinionated, there must be benchmark for random read and either JSON is faster or SQL, it's as opinionated as a question whether light faster than wind).

2. How to write Python code with inline tags. No more opinionated than question how to do bubble sort.

3. How do i access JSON file with jQuery?

Comment: 1. It depends, JSON might be faster in very small datasets but SQL is more scalable and will be faster as your dataset grows. I would recommend you use SQL (but this is my opinion, someone might prefer json to the bitter end).
2. I'd use wsgi for this (but this is my opinion, there are probably many libraries to do this).
3. I'd make an XHR request (but this is my opinion, you can probably send the json with the original payload).